# Unable to pass state value through react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to pass the state of my functions through below, i have added {state.name.user} and also {onInputChange} but i am running into errors.

```
<Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={onRouteChange} />
            { route === 'home'
              ? <div>
                  <Logo />
                  <Rank
                    name={state.user.name}
                    entries={state.user.entries}
                  />
                  <ImageLinkForm
                    onInputChange={onInputChange}
                    onButtonSubmit={onButtonSubmit}
                  />
                  <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
                </div>
              : (
                 route === 'signin'
                 ? <Signin loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange}/>
                 : <Register loadUser={loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange}/>
                )
            }
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show the errors and your state definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix, for

```
<Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
            { route === 'home'
              ? <div>
                  <Logo />
                  <Rank
                    name={this.state.user.name}
                    entries={this.state.user.entries}
                  />
                  <ImageLinkForm
                    onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                    onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
                  />
                  <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
                </div>
              : (
                 route === 'signin'
                 ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange}/>
                 : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={onRouteChange}/>
                )
            }
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Always make sure you pass through ".this" before.